# How to make a label display in a vertical list but still hold the properties of inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm using some labels for some radio buttons because I love the ability to click on the text to effect the radio button. I want them to display in a vertical list. The problem is currently they are displaying as block so they spread across the whole page and a user could click on the white space to the right of the answer to activate it.

I know I can wrap the label in a div, and have the div display block and have the contained label display inline-block. The problem with this is I have 100's of labels I would need to adjust for this change so I'd prefer to do it with straight CSS if possible.

I was also able to use float: left and clear: both to get a desired effect but the problem with this was other elements on the page were not displaying similarly and dramatically effect by this.

```css
label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio"/>
  answer
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio"/>
  answer
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio"/>
  answer
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio"/>
  answer
 </label>
```

Comment: I was able to get the desired effect adding margin-right: 50% and removing display: block. But this seems like a bad way to fix this and I'm sure will have issues on smaller screens. Is there a way to have margin-right always fill the extra space?

Comment: Typically you'd just put a <br> after each label... I know you said you have 100's, but it should be easy with a find/replace tool that most text editors have.

Comment: just remove `display: block;` why is that even there if you don't want them to display as blocks?

Comment: @Pamblam he wants display block to put them on separate lines, but he does not want the 100% width that comes along with it.

Comment: thank you for clarification.. my answer should achieve that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Use the `::after` pseudo element to fill the rest of the line, like this:

```
label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

---

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/rycdvaqb/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" />answer
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" />answer
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" />answer
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" />answer
</label>
```

---

**SIDE NOTE:**

As a side note, if you want to have older browser support you can use `:after` instead of `::after`. The difference is that one is CSS2 syntax and the other CSS3, respectively.

In CSS3 they changed the syntax to differentiate between [psuedo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

> IE8 only supports the single-colon CSS 2.1 syntax (i.e. :pseudo-class). It does not support the double-colon CSS3 syntax (i.e. ::pseudo-element).

Comment: Thank's Ricardo! I was having a little trouble with this at first but found that bootstrap was applying a display: inline-block to the label element. I had to reset it to the initial style of display: inline for it to work. After that it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear that, for those kind of issues you can always use the initial keyword in your css property. For example: display: initial; this will reset it to its default value.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the br after each element and remove display:block..

```
label::after {
    content: "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this. It might an awkward spacing on the last remaining label but I can always find a way around it.

Comment: @Jleibham - I believe you can do a negative bottom margin on the parent element to compensate.. `margin-bottom: -1em;`

Comment: also, the solution proposed by Ricardo takes that into account.

Comment: It is important to know that the content property in pseudo-elements does not allow inserting HTML. This will not be rendered just displayed as normal text.

Answer (score 0):

Use property `display:block` and `width:100%` properties to make the `label` stretch to parent's width. Use `text-align: center;` property to *horizontally align* the text inside the `label`.

```
label{
  display:block; 
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what I'm trying to achieve. I want the input/labels to be aligned to the left and stacked in a vertical list, but I want the width to be set like inline-block.